# Am I allowed to use company work in my portfolio?

Tags: client-relations, legal, portfolio

This was one of my first clients. I want to use the work I've done to market myself as a designer & marketer but I'm afraid of legal backlash for using company information.

Here's the catch, although I was working "for hire" - there is

1. No legally binding contract (I was sending contracts at the beginning & it became a he said she said with him promising me a bunch of things he didn't follow through with. There's maybe 3 files that he legally owns. All the rest he didn't want contracts for.)
2. I filed taxes as a 1099 independent
3. I provided all of my own equipment and tools (computer, apps, & drive)
4. They didn't provide me with benefits (health) and only provided a workspace.

I ended up ceasing work with them because I was being exploited (less than 10k within a year) for all the work I was doing. With all that being said, I know I technically own copyrights since I had spoke briefly with a copyright attorney about it asking for some legal advice. I also looked into laws and work for hire regulations so I'd say I'm in the clear.

But now I'm concerned about using the work for my portfolio and marketing myself as the sole designer that practically carried the company. What do I do? Should I remove the logo & company information? Does it matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who owns authorship when an employee makes a design for their employer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55201/who-owns-authorship-when-an-employee-makes-a-design-for-their-employer) or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1708/who-owns-the-design or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58199/designer-right-to-obtain-digital-copies-of-work-done-as-an-employee-of-company or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74604/do-i-own-the-rights-to-show-my-designs-in-my-portfolio

Comment: We can't and don't really give legal advice here. And that's sort of what you are asking.  I will say that contracts, if *ever* agreed to, tend to carry over. Even if every single project didn't have a separate contract, many terms from a previously agreed upon contract *may* be seen as enforce. But I am not a lawyer... and haven't even played one on TV.